# ASP.net: Opening and closing database connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, database-connection

I have this code which first checks if a particular`prodName` already exists in the database. If it does exist, I have to update `quantity` of that `prodName`. If not, I have to insert the data. What my question is, Is this a good code? I mean is it a good practice to open and close  connections like this or is there any way i can improve it? Like for every query i have to write these opening and closing lines everytime. Can any one suggest a good method to save these repetitive lines of code or Its just done this way?

```
public static void manageStock(CompanyStock stock)
        {

            cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from tblStock where prodName=@prodName", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);
            int count;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //returns null if doesnt exist
            }

            finally {
                con.Close();
            }


            if (count > 0)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select quantity from tblStock where prodName=@prodName", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    qty = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
                }

                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }

                stock.quantity += qty;
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblStock set quantity = @quantity where prodName=@prodName", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", stock.quantity);

            }
            else
            {

                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblStock(prodName,quantity) values (@prodName, @quantity)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName",stock.prodName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity",stock.quantity);

            }


            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> using

```
public static void manageStock(CompanyStock stock)
    {

        using(var con=new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
        {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from tblStock where prodName=@prodName", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);
        int count;


        count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //returns null if doesnt exist


        if (count > 0)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select quantity from tblStock where prodName=@prodName", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);

            qty = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 


            stock.quantity += qty;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblStock set quantity = @quantity where prodName=@prodName", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", stock.prodName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", stock.quantity);

        }
        else
        {

            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblStock(prodName,quantity) values (@prodName, @quantity)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName",stock.prodName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity",stock.quantity);

        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code throws exception: `ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.`

Answer (score 0):

you may check it's state before opening like,

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
```